# Uso Chrome, Selenium y Python. Los metodos Locate_element(By funcionan en algunos casos: By.TAG_NAME,value='p' sí, pero By.TAG_NAME,value='form' no

Tags: python, selenium

Tengo este código Python

```
    
    self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,value='form')
        
    # self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,value='script') OK
      
    # self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,value='p') OK
      
    # self.driver.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME,value='form') ERROR
       
    # self.driver.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME,value='h1') OK
       
    # self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h1') OK 
    # self.driver.find_element_by_id("classic")   ERROR
    # self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'textarea') ERROR
    # self.driver.find_element(By.ID,'classic')   ERROR
    # self.driver.find_element(By.ID,('editor')) ERROR
```

Las líneas comentadas con ERROR indican los casos erróneos.
En esos casos, el log indica:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"form"}

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No entiendo que error estoy cometiendo. Supuestamente las lineas comentadas con ERROR respetan la sintaxis de find_element. Ej: find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'form')
Sin embargo solo son exitosos algunos casos (los que figuran con OK)

Comment: No entiendo qué error estoy cometiendo. En algunos casos find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'p') funciona. En otros tags no funciona (By.TAG_NAME,'form'). Por favor, indiquen cual es mi error.